# Sphere renders look imperfect in Blender 2.79

Tags: rendering

I'm just trying out a very basic render whilst getting to grips with Blender

I've created a sphere and exported as a PNG, but the sphere looks quite wobbly and imperfect. I just exported it using the default HDTV settings.

See the attached image, I've drawn a perfect circle around it in Photoshop so you can see how off it is:

[image]

But when I view the sphere in 3D View in Blender it looks fine.

Any anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Hello :). This could be a perspective distortion, if the sphere isn't dead center in frame.

Comment: I think a sphere is always round whatever angle/perspective you are viewing it from.

Comment: @Sanbaldo Try it for yourself - distance from center and lower focal length can distort significantly :).

Comment: @JachymMichal, you are right! (but the shape is still a "soft round" if you have enough details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a "subdivision surface" modifier to add more geometry.
Check that the level of subdivision surface is the same between "viewport and render".

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the downvote? so I can help adding info to my answer